# Erro ao realizar update Mysql com chaves compostas

Tags: mysql

Tenho a seguinte tabela no Mysql 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei de todas as formas realizar um sql de update porem todas as vezes retorna o mesmo erro abaixo.

> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails

Esse é o sql de update

```
UPDATE ACDM_TREI_RLZD_ALU_EXCC SET EST_EXCC = 'OK' WHERE CD_ALU = 1 AND TS_RLZC_TREI = '2019-02-16' AND NR_EXCC= 1
```

Essa é a tabela em que ela é dependente
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguma ideia do que posso estar errando?

Comment: Essa coluna EST_EXCC é referenciada em outra table?

Comment: Não. Ela é uma coluna comum

Comment: Manda o create table dessa tabela.

Comment: Editei a pergunta e coloquei o create

Comment: O update foi normal aqui.

UPDATE ACDM_TREI_RLZD_ALU_EXCC SET EST_EXCC = 'OK' 
WHERE CD_ALU = 1 AND
date(TS_RLZC_TREI) = '2019-02-16' AND
NR_EXCC= 1

Comment: qualquer coisa manda as outras tables que ele utiliza como foreign

Comment: Coloquei na pergunta as tabelas relacionadas

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89808/discussion-between-bilico-and-user129333).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No create abaixo você está usando a coluna `TS_RLZC_TREI` da tabela `ACDM_TREI_RLZD_ALU_EXCC` como chave estrangeira. Porém o valor dela que é referência está atualizando sempre que você da um update devido o comando do create.

```
#`TS_RLZC_TREI` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp(),
```

O create ficaria desta forma:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ACDM_TREI_RLZD_ALU_EXCC` (
  `CD_ALU` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `TS_RLZC_TREI` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(), /*A alteração está aqui*/
  `NR_EXCC` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CD_EXCC` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `QT_SRE` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `QT_RPTC` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `HR_DESC` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `QT_KG` decimal(15,3) DEFAULT NULL,
  `HR_DRCO` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `TX_OBS` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TS_ULT_ALT` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `CD_USU_RSP` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `EST_EXCC` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```